# Slack slash command user token

Tags: oauth-2.0, passport.js, slack

We've got a team Slack app and some slash commands configured with them. The slash commands are sending requests to a express REST endpoint which uses passport-slack as authentication.

I want that the requests generated by the slash commands to include the access token for the user since it's already logged in to Slack, but not just the verification token

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this, since it would breach Slack's security architecture and should also be unnecessary if your app is designed according to Slack's standards.

Your app only needs to retrieve and store the user token once during the installation process and can then use it for all future API calls indefinitely, since it does not have an expiry date. They also do not need to be refreshed.

Usually you would install a Slack app only once per Slack team and use that token for all future API calls. This is done using the OAauth 2.0 protocol, which ensured the token is generated in a secure way.

But if you really want the user token from every user, you can ask every user to install your Slack app. Its call "configurations" and that way you get all user tokens. But again, you only need to do that once and you should do it with the Oauth process.

Comment: But isn't it unsafer to store all your users' tokens on your server instead of receiving them on every request and using it without storing it at all?

Comment: No, its pretty much standard practice for Slack apps. Of course your app needs to keep them safe, but its normal to store the token for each workspace in the app's database.

Comment: And the Slack token are not one-time-tokens. They never expire and are meant to be created once and then stored safely by the Slack app for later use.

Comment: Here is the official post from Slack on the topic: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-safety